# C# get method string name using expressions

Tags: c#

I need something like this:

```
public string GetName<Type>(Expression<Somestuffhere>) // will bet GetName<Foo>(o => o.Do())
{
   ...
   return "Execute";
}
```

Comment: get the string name of a method for some class/Type

Comment: Take a look at [Daniel Cazzulino's blog](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2007/12/30/49063.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is`(expression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.Name`